# Image not responsive when scrolled on mobile

Tags: css, responsive

Whenever my image hits the width of an iphone six or lower and is scrolled to the left, there is a margin.

1. Image not scrolled - https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMkb2.png
2. Image scrolled to the left - https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxcQb.png

My CSS:

```
.background-image {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  background:         
    linear-gradient(rgba(74,74,74,0.21), rgba(74,74,74,0.21)), 
    url('./img/nyc_quarter.png') no-repeat center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: this is usually a case of some other content on the page being too wide - often times something with a negative margin (`.row` in bootstrap for example), something with a fixed/minimum width larger than your current viewport, or an absolute positioned element positioned farther right than the width of your viewport

Comment: why your div is in position:absolute ?

Comment: on second look, it would seem the width of your table cannot get any smaller because the headings are as narrow as they can get at their current font size. see if temporarily hiding the table fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

do you want somethink like this ?

```css
nav
{
  background-color:black;
  height:30px;
  color:white;
}

#background
{
  background-image: url('https://weloveminitel.eu/snow2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height:200px;
  color:white;
  display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: stretch;
text-align:center;
  
}

#bottom
{
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid black;
  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    navbar
  </nav>
  <div id="background">
    some text
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
  the bottom div
  </div>
</body>
```